# Trying to loop over countries and states for Drupal 7 form select box with optgroups

Tags: forms, loops, drupal, drupal-7, drop-down-menu

I am creating a form using the Drupal 7 form API. One of my fields is a select box of countries and states. I am only using 5 countries. The goal is to have the select box have optgroups for the countries and under that each state/province for that country. In HTML it would be like this:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="United States">
  <option value="AK">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  ...
  <optgroup label="Canada">
  <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
  <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I have a hardcoded array of countries and I am getting the states including country name from the dB. I am trying to contruct my options array for the select box, but for some reason, it is only working for the first country in the list, in this case, the United States. Here is my code:

```
// get list of states from dB
$states = db_query('SELECT state_code, state_name, country_name FROM {states}');

$countries = array(
  'US' => 'United States',
  'CAN' => 'Canada',
  'AU' => 'Australia',
  'NZ' => 'New Zealand',
  'BM' => 'Bermuda'
);

foreach($countries as $country_code => $country_name) {
  $states_options[$country_name] = array();
  foreach($states as $state) {
    if($country_name == $state->country_name) {
      $states_options[$country_name][$state->state_code] = $state->state_name;
    }
  }
}

$form['location'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $states_options,
  '#required' => FALSE,
);
```

which ends up yielding:

```
<select style="width:80%;" id="edit-location" name="location" class="form-select">
   <optgroup label="United States">
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
      <option value="CA">California</option>
      <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
      <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
      <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
      <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
      <option value="FL">Florida</option>
      <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
      <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
      <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
      <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
      <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
      <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
      <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
      <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
      <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
      <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
      <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
      <option value="ME">Maine</option>
      <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
      <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
      <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
      <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
      <option value="MT">Montana</option>
      <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
      <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
      <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
      <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
      <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
      <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
      <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
      <option value="NY">New York</option>
      <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
      <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
      <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
      <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
      <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
      <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
      <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
      <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
      <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="TX">Texas</option>
      <option value="UT">Utah</option>
      <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
      <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
      <option value="WA">Washington</option>
      <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
      <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      <option value="VI">U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
      <option value="GU">Guam</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Canada">
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Australia">
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="New Zealand">    
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Bermuda">     
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

UPDATE:

Ok so I figured out that it was because of the way I was constructing the query. I was originally using this:

```
$states= db_query('SELECT state_code, state_name, country_name FROM {states}');
```

Which gave me what I needed and I could do a foreach and loop over $states and echo out the values just fine, but if I did a var_dump on $states, I wouldn't get the actual records, I would get a bunch of information about the query and the actual query that was executed etc. Maybe I needed to use a specific type of fetch method. Anyway I ended up switching it to:

```
$states = db_select('states', 's')
  ->fields('s')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
```

and it worked without me changing any of my looping code.

Comment: If you var_dump($states) before you loop the countries does it show the states for the other countries?

Comment: The var_dump did reveal something. I think I was not fetching the records correctly. I COULD do a foreach over $states and it would echo out the correct values including all states and countries, but the var_dump itself dumped out query execution information as opposed to the actual records. I think I needed to do a specific fetch to get the records correctly. Anyway, I updated my original post to show you what I ended up using that worked.

THANKS

Comment: ARG so I'm stupid. I DID need a fetch on there. This is what need up working also with the old way of constructing the query: $states = db_query('SELECT state_code, state_name, country_name FROM {states}')->fetchAll(); I needed that fetchAll() on there. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I saw that in the docs, but because I could immediately do a foreach around $states, I thought I was good.